# C# selenium unable to find an element

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I'm new in C# and Selenium then I apologize in advance for my trivial question. I'm trying to automate the reading of numbers in a counter in a web page, below is the portion of HTML that concerns the above counter:

```
<div class="row counter_container_div" xpath="1">
 <h1 class="counter"> 
   <span id="multiplier_first_digit" style="">0</span> 
   <span id="multiplier_second_digit">9</span> 
   <span id="multiplier_third_digit" style="">4</span> 
   <span id="multiplier_fourth_digit" style="">2</span> 
   <span id="multiplier_fifth_digit" class="margin_right0">7</span>
 </h1>
</div>
```

This is instead the piece of C # code to try to find the third digit of the counter:

```
var digit = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@id='multiplier_third_digit']")).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(digit);
        Console.Read();
```

The result that the console returns to me is as follows:

Element (id = 0.9456097574416866-3)

Why? How do I get the result that is present in the HTML code that would be 4?
Thanks for all your help.
See you soon

Comment: because here `.ToString()` means you are converting the locator to string. Use `.Text` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `Text` property. Using `ToString()` is returning info of the webelement object.

Also, as a general Selenium suggestion, I would recommend using the `By.Id` selector in this case. Your xpath will work, but using ID is easier to both read and write, and it'll technically be processed a bit faster by WebDriver. So, try this:

```
var digit = driver.FindElement(By.Id("multiplier_third_digit")).Text;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works. In your opinion, is there a way to read the element when the counter stops? now I use a "Thread.Sleep (5000)" wait function.

Comment: Thread.Sleep() works, but generally you want to avoid using it. A better way is to use `WebDriverWait`. If you want to wait until something does NOT exist, for example, you can do: `new WebDriverWait(driver, Timespan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.Xpath('whatever selector you want)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to get text

```
var digit = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@id='multiplier_third_digit']")).Text;
```